# Using cmd to move files with a specific filename mask

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to use a simple windows cmd command to move a set of .csv files from one directory to another.

I know that this can be easily achieved through:

```
MOVE "*.csv" "D:/lorik_home"
```

The issue comes when I want to only move some specific files with a filename mask, for instance, I want to move all files which are in the .csv extension and start with the name: `lorik_files_`. I already tried using:

```
MOVE "lorik_files_*.csv" "D:/lorik_home"
```

This works when there is only one file of the format: `lorik_files_20112233_09_33_33.csv`, but when there are two files with the masks such as:

```
lorik_files_20112233_09_33_33.csv
lorik_files_20112233_10_23_42.csv
```

I get an error such as:

> A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found.

I need a hand for capturing those filename prefix masks, conditioned by .csv extension at the end.

Comment: `MOVE "lorik_files_*.csv" "D:\lorik_home\"`?

Comment: …or `Move /Y "lorik_files_*.csv" "D:\lorik_home"`, using the correct Windows path separator, the backslash, _(reverse solidus)_.